# How to Redistribute MSXML Library?

Tags: xml, redistributable, msxml6

I plan to redistribute MSXML library with my program. Based on the online document at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc507432(v=vs.80) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc507436(v=vs.80) , the latest version of MSXML is 6.0. However, after visiting the download page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb190622(v=msdn.10) , under MSXML Downloads section, there are no MSXML 6.0 at all. The only one available is SQLXML 3.0.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML) 6.0 redistributable from the Microsoft download center at this address: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988

Comment: I study the link you provided. It seems there are 4 files, msxml6.msi,msxml6_ia64.msi,msxml6_SDK.msi,msxml6_x64.msi. There are no documents on them, so I guess 1 is the redistributable file, 2 is for IA64 system, 3 is the development kit, and 4 is for x64 system. Is that correct?

Comment: URL says 404. Is it moved somewhere else?